# Set a conditional divide function with NA values present

Tags: r, dataframe, conditional-statements

I have a snippet of a larger data set that I am trying convert to the same unit of measurement. I can convert the columns "unit1" and "legal1" to "ppm" units just fine, but I run into trouble when trying to convert "unit2" and "legal2" to "ppm" units.

When the unit is "ppb" in the corresponding columns, I need the values in "legal" columns to divide by 1000.

Here is my progress so far:

```
contaminants <- c("Barium", "Magnanese", "Nitrate", "Nitrate & nitrite")
unit1 <- c("ppb", "ppb", "ppm", "ppm")
legal1 <- c(2000, 50, 10, 10)
legal2 <- c(2, 999999, 10, NA)
unit2 <- c("ppm", "ppb", "ppm", NA)

testdf = data.frame(contaminants, unit1, legal1, unit2, legal2)
testdf
```

I can successfully convert the "unit1" and "legal1" to "ppm" units with

```
testdf$legal1[testdf$unit1 == "ppb"] <- (testdf$legal1)/1000
testdf$unit1[testdf$unit1 == "ppb"] <- "ppm"
```

When I try to run the same code for "unit2" and "legal2"

```
testdf$legal2[testdf$unit2 == "ppb"] <- (testdf$legal2)/1000
```

I get the following error:
"NAs are not allowed in subscripted assignments"

In this case, only the row with 'Magnanese' would need to be divided by 1000, but that's not happening.

Comment: You can use `which(testdf$unit1 == "ppb")` instead.  This line has a logic bug: `testdf$legal1[testdf$unit1 == "ppb"] <- (testdf$legal1)/1000`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is another `tidyverse` solution. The issue is cause by the `NA` we could address it by `!is.na(.)` within `across`. The challenge is to fulfill the condition to be `ppb` to calculate:

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)

testdf %>%
  mutate(across(starts_with("legal"), 
                ~ if_else(get(str_replace(cur_column(), "legal", "unit")) == "ppb" & !is.na(.), . / 1000, .),
                .names = "{.col}"),
         across(starts_with("unit"), ~ifelse(. == "ppb", "ppm", .)))
```

OR in base R with a custom function:

```
# custom function 
transform_fun <- function(df, legal_col, unit_col) {
  ifelse(df[[unit_col]] == "ppb" & !is.na(df[[legal_col]]), df[[legal_col]] / 1000, df[[legal_col]])
}


testdf$legal1 <- transform_fun(testdf, "legal1", "unit1")
testdf$unit1 <- ifelse(testdf$unit1 == "ppb", "ppm", testdf$unit1)

testdf$legal2 <- transform_fun(testdf, "legal2", "unit2")
testdf$unit2 <- ifelse(testdf$unit2 == "ppb", "ppm", testdf$unit2)

testdf
```

```
       contaminants unit1 legal1 unit2  legal2
1            Barium   ppm   2.00   ppm   2.000
2         Magnanese   ppm   0.05   ppm 999.999
3           Nitrate   ppm  10.00   ppm  10.000
4 Nitrate & nitrite   ppm  10.00  <NA>      NA
```

Comment: This is exactly what I needed! I tried a variety of ways using ifelse and !is.na(), but I couldn't quite get the right sequence. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

Currently, your dataset does not have this condition, `testdf$unit2 == "ppb"`, and hence the `NA` warning in your attempted assignment. As an alternative, consider `ifelse` to handle cases that do and do not follow a specific condition. Below uses `within` to adjust data frames columns in an encapsulated context without needing the repetitive `testdf$` reference:

```r
testdf <- within(
  testdf, {
    legal1 <- ifelse(unit1 == "ppb", (legal1)/1000, legal1)
    unit1 <- ifelse(unit1 == "ppb", "ppm", unit1)

    legal2 <- ifelse(unit2 == "ppb", (legal2)/1000, legal2)
    unit2 <- ifelse(unit2 == "ppb", "ppm", unit2)
  }
)
```

However, consider avoiding wide formatted data with suffixed columns. Instead, keep data in long, [tidy](https://r4ds.hadley.nz/data-tidy.html) format which facilitates cleaning, merging, aggregating, modeling, graphing, and other analytical needs. And once reshaped, you can clean only *one* set of variables. Below uses `reshape` to transform data from wide to long format and calls `ifelse`:

```r
long_df <- reshape(
  testdf,
  idvar = "contaminants",
  varying = list(
    grepl("unit", names(testdf)),
    grepl("legal", names(testdf))
  ),
  v.names = c("unit", "legal"),
  timevar = "var_num",
  direction = "long",
  new.row.names = 1:10E4
)

long_df <- within(
  long_df, {
    legal <- ifelse(unit == "ppb", (legal)/1000, legal)
    unit <- ifelse(unit == "ppb", "ppm", unit)
  }
)

long_df
#        contaminants var_num unit   legal
# 1            Barium       1  ppm   2.000
# 2         Magnanese       1  ppm   0.050
# 3           Nitrate       1  ppm  10.000
# 4 Nitrate & nitrite       1  ppm  10.000
# 5            Barium       2  ppm   2.000
# 6         Magnanese       2  ppm 999.999
# 7           Nitrate       2  ppm  10.000
# 8 Nitrate & nitrite       2 <NA>      NA
```